# Node.js Redis connection pooling not working correctly in netlify functions

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis, netlify-function

I'm trying to use connection pooling to manage Redis connections in my Node.js application, but I'm running into issues where the connected clients to the database is being exceeded and new client connections are being created even though connection is released after returning response.
I'm using netlify functions and redis cloud free tier which has only 30 connections.

Here's the code I'm using to create the connection pool:

```
const Redis = require('ioredis-rejson');
const { createPool } = require('generic-pool');

const pool = createPool({
  create: () => new Redis({
    port:xx,
    host : "xx",
    password :"xx",
    username: "",
    keyPrefix: 'myapp:'
  }),
  destroy: client => client.disconnect(),
  max: 10, // maximum number of connections to create at once
  min: 2, // minimum number of connections to keep in the pool
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a connection can be idle before being released
  acquireTimeoutMillis: 5000, // how long to wait for a connection to become available
});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(`Acquiring connection from pool (size=${pool.size}, available=${pool.available})`);
    let client;
    try {
      // acquire a connection from the pool
      client = await pool.acquire();
      console.log(`Acquired connection: ${client.address}`);
      const cachedResult = await client.json_get('results');
      console.log(`Retrieved connection: ${client.address}`);
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(cachedResult),
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify('Something went wrong'),
      };
    } finally {
      // always release the connection back to the pool
      if (client) {
        pool.release(client);
        console.log(`Released connection: ${client.address}`);
      }
    }
  };
```

Also, for some reason, client.address is `undefined` when console logged and `pool (size=0, available=0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with Redis hanging on to disconnected connections before and resulting in too many connections. Not sure if it's a server setting or what but I've seen it in multiple languages.

Regardless and for that reason, I always call `.quit` instead—even though it's soon to be deprecated. The QUIT command is actually received and processed by Redis and *Redis* ends the connection.

Comment: I removed the pooling logic now. After researching i found out there is an issue with containerization.  so i just make the connection. query the db , close the connection. the technique is not recommended but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of utilizing a separate package to manage connection pooling, I opted to initialize Redis as a singleton throughout the project. By doing so, I adjusted the isolationPoolOptions as needed to control the connection pool behavior.

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';
const redisClient = createClient({
  url: <url>,
  isolationPoolOptions: {
    min: 1,
    max: 30
  })
}
```